# Count of similar characters without repetition, in two strings

Tags: c, string

I have written a C program to find out the number of similar characters between two strings. If a character is repeated again it shouldn't count it.

Like if you give an input of

```
everest
every
```

The output should be

```
3
```

Because the four letters "ever" are identical, but the repeated "e" does not increase the count.

For the input

```
apothecary
panther
```

the output should be 6, because of "apther", not counting the second "a".

My code seems like a bulk one for a short process. My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char firstString[100], secondString[100], similarChar[100], uniqueChar[100] = {0};
   fgets(firstString, 100, stdin);
   fgets(secondString, 100, stdin);
   int firstStringLength = strlen(firstString) - 1, secondStringLength = strlen(secondString) - 1, counter, counter1, count = 0, uniqueElem, uniqueCtr = 0;
   for(counter = 0; counter < firstStringLength; counter++) {
       for(counter1 = 0; counter1 < secondStringLength; counter1++) {
           if(firstString[counter] == secondString[counter1]){
               similarChar[count] = firstString[counter];
               count++;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   for(counter = 0; counter < strlen(similarChar); counter++) {
       uniqueElem = 0;
       for(counter1 = 0; counter1 < counter; counter1++) {
          if(similarChar[counter] == uniqueChar[counter1]) {
              uniqueElem++;
          }
       }
       if(uniqueElem == 0) {
           uniqueChar[uniqueCtr++] = similarChar[counter];
       }
       }
   if(strlen(uniqueChar) > 1) {
    printf("%d\n", strlen(uniqueChar));
    printf("%s", uniqueChar);
   } else {
   printf("%d",0);
   }
}
```

Can someone please provide me some suggestions or code for shortening this function?

Comment: In your sample input, you have only one Input string.

Comment: Why should the output be 3? I count 4 similar/identical characters.

Comment: So, if the inputs were 'apothecary' and 'panther', would the count be 6?  What about 'abacus' and 'abracadabra' — 3?

Comment: Yeah it's 4 but e is repeating again. So it should just take the count as 3. If a character is repeated again it shouldn't count it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes the count would be 6 and for the next one it'd be 3 yeah!

Comment: What result do you want for "ABc" "DBc"? I.e. please elaborate on which characters in the input have to be handled. Only lowercase alphabetic? All alphabetic? Alphanumeric? Alphanumeric and whitespace? Punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have 2 Arrays to keep a count of the number of occurrences of each aplhabet.

```
int arrayCount1[26],arrayCount2[26];
```

Loop through strings and store the occurrences.

Now for counting the similar number of characters use:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++ ){
   similarCharacters = similarCharacters + min( arrayCount1[26], arrayCount2[26] )
}
```

Comment: Can you please append this with the whole code of mine? It's kinda confusing :(

Comment: What is confusing?

Comment: You are making assumptions on which character should count, only 26. The other answer is more robust and goes further with the counting optimisation.

Comment: The only assumption I am making according to the sample input in the question is that he only need to count the similar alphabets between two string.

Comment: Question has "characters" not "letters", not "alphabetic letters", not "lower case alphabetic letters". I count at least two, maybe three, assumptions made by you which are not given by the question.

Comment: The Sample input provided should be more robust.

Comment: You should clarify before assuming.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to go. Take an array and map the ascii code as an index to that array. Say `int arr[256]={0}`;

Now whatever character you see in string-1 mark `1` for that. `arr[string[i]]=1`; Marking what characters appeared in the first string.

Now again when looping through the characters of string-2 increase the value of `arr[string2[i]]++` **only if** `arr[i]` is `1`. Now we are tallying that yes this characters appeared here also.

Now check how many positions of the array contains  `2`. That is the answer.

```
int arr[256]={0};
for(counter = 0; counter < firstStringLength; counter++) 
    arr[firstString[counter]]=1;
for(counter = 0; counter < secondStringLength; counter++) 
    if(arr[secondString[counter]]==1)
      arr[secondString[counter]]++;

int ans = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  ans += (arr[i]==2);
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? I don't understand the last point.

Comment: @RameshSekhar.: Edited. You will get the idea now.

Comment: @RameshSekhar.: The answer you selected is making assumtions..this is more genralized. Be careful when you select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified approach to achieve your goal. You should create an array to hold the characters that has been seen for the first time.

Then, you'll have to make two loops. The first is unconditional, while the second is conditional; That condition is dependent on a variable that you have to create, which checks weather the end of one of the strings has been reached.

Ofcourse, the checking for the end of the other string should be within the first unconditional loop. You can make use of the `strchr()` function to count the common characters without repetition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(const char *s1, const char *s2);

int main(void)
{
    printf("count: %d\n", foo("everest", "every"));
    printf("count: %d\n", foo("apothecary", "panther"));
    printf("count: %d\n", foo("abacus", "abracadabra"));
    return 0;
}


int foo(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int condition = 0;
    int count = 0;

    size_t n = 0;
    char buf[256] = { 0 };

    // part 1
    while (s2[n])
    {
        if (strchr(s1, s2[n]) && !strchr(buf, s2[n]))
        {
            buf[count++] = s2[n];
        }
        if (!s1[n]) {
            condition = 1;
        }
        n++;
    }
    // part 2
    if (!condition ) {
        while (s1[n]) {
            if (strchr(s2, s1[n]) && !strchr(buf, s1[n]))
            {
                buf[count++] = s1[n];
            }
            n++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

NOTE: You should check for buffer overflow, and you should use a dynamic approach to reallocate memory accordingly, but this is a demo.